# Proof of limit point ( accumulation point )

Tags: general-topology, analysis, proof-writing

Let $(X, d)$ be a metric space. Let $A ⊂ X$ and $x ∈ X$. Prove the following:

> $x$ is a limit point of $A$ if and only if $∀ v ∈ V $, $V$ neighborhood of $x$,  then $V ∩ A$ is infinite.

I know this:

Definition of a limit point: $x$ is a limit point of $S$ provided that every neighborhood of $x$ contains elements from $S$ distinct from $x$.

But I don't know how to prove the claim.

Comment: Hint: for any finite set of points, there exists a minimum distance between pairs of points.

Comment: Hint for @Paul's Hint: For any finite set of points, there exists a finite number of pairs of points.

Comment: Welcome to MSE, Adnsna! I edit a bit your post, please take care of spelling and Latex and... good luck!

Comment: Thank you @Andrea ! And thank you all for hints, but I still have no idea how to make it :(

Comment: You're welcome. Don't worry: put some effort in making your question neat and clear and here on MSE many people will give you good suggestions and answers!

Comment: $\forall v\in V\dots$? I considered it $\forall V\dots$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Imagine graphically in a neighborhood (open ball) $V$ of $x$ a finite number of points of A. This contradict the notion of limit point. In fact, you can reduce the initial neighborhood $V$ so that it no contains the finite number of common points $A$ and $V$.

For contradiction, suppose that there exists $V$ neighborhood of $x$ that contains a finite number points of $A$. Enumerate the points
$$ (A\setminus \{x\})\cap V= \{a_1,a_2,\dots,a_n\}$$
then $$ r=\min \{ d(a_i,x)\colon i=1,\dots,n\}$$
is strictly positive. Let $\tilde{V}=\left\{ y\in X\colon d(y,x)<\frac{r}{2} \right\}$ then we have that 
$$ (A\setminus \{x\})\cap \tilde{V} = \emptyset.$$
I.e., $\tilde{V}$ is neighborhood of $x$ that no contains some point of $A$ distinct of $x$, this a contradiction. Therefore, every neighborhood $V$ of $x$ contains a infinite number points of $A$.